# Laravel: For each where clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm trying to return a query that has an arbitrary amount of where clauses based on the number of tags a user submits.

---

```
//unknown number of ids to query on
$tag_ids = array(1,5);

//multiple joins with closure
$items = DB::table('archives_items_metadata')->join('tags', 'archives_items_metadata.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id')->join('archives_items', 'archives_items_metadata.archive_item_id', '=', 'archives_items.id')->join('items', 'archives_items.item_id', '=', 'items.id')
                ->where(function ($query) use ($tag_ids) {

                    foreach ($tag_ids as $tag_id)
                    {
                        $query->where('archives_items_metadata.tag_id', $tag_id);
                    }

                })->get();
```

---

The result I get is an empty array even though when I try array(1) or array(5) by themselves, they both return the same item. What am I missing?

EDIT::
I'm looking to return items that have each of the tag ids specified. The reference of items to tags is stored on the archives_items_metadata table. How can I get the result I'm expecting, and what's the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: How can the same row have two (or more) different values for the same field?

Comment: How do you accomplish a query on a many to many table where there is an intersection for the data you're trying to return?

Comment: Basically you want the `whereIn('archives_items_metadata.tag_id', $tag_ids)` as @Victory said and restrict this result with `HAVING COUNT(<other_id_field>) = number of elements in IN()`. I'm sure there's an eloquent way to achieve this.

Comment: As @VMai suggested you need to use `where in()` and count. If you are querying `Eloquent` model, then I can show you how. Otherwise (`DB::table...`) you need to use raw statements.

Comment: In many cases you can use the same methods that are available on eloquent models as on queries. I am also a strong proponent of using DB class over a model that extends eloquent when building an API that returns many records as Eloquent creates many accessor properties that increase the amount of time to return a response. I had a case where switching my app from Model:: to DB::('model') decreased json response time from 2000ms to 400ms. You just have to write more code yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to do a `WHERE tag_id IN (1, 2, 3)` style clause `laravel` has the `whereIn($col, $vals)` builder function.

```
->whereIn('archives_items_metadata.tag_id', $tag_ids)
```

[search for "whereIn" in the official docs](http://laravel.com/docs/queries)

Comment: This produces an unexpected result. This expands the results, rather than contracts.

Comment: @egekhter - `WHERE foo IN (1, 2, 3)` is the same as `WHERE foo = 1 OR foo = 2 OR foo = 3` is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for && clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tag_count = count($tag_ids);
$items = DB::table('archives_items')->join('archives_items_metadata', 'archives_items_metadata.archive_item_id', '=', 'archives_items.id')->join('tags', 'archives_items_metadata.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id')
->whereIn('archives_items_metadata.tag_id', $tag_ids)->whereNull('archives_items_metadata.deleted_at')
->groupBy('archives_items_metadata.archive_item_id')->havingRaw('count(*)='.$tag_count->get();
```